# How do i get the PsiMethodCallExpression object type?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

How do I get the object type that a PsiMethodCallExpression refers to?

eg

Object x = new Object;
x.hashCode();

I can use the visitor and get the PsiMethodCallExpression, and I can get "hashCode", but how do I get "Object"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can learn from the javadocs to the APIs in question, you can obtain the method being called by calling `PsiMethodCallExpression.resolveMethod()`, and after that you can obtain the class where the method is declared by calling `PsiMethod.getContainingClass()`.

Edit - just added some code to make it obvious for all and sundry, use the "accept" method with the following:

```
public void visitMethodCallExpression(PsiMethodCallExpression expression) {
       super.visitCallExpression(expression);
       PsiUtil.getMemberQualifiedName(expression.resolveMethod());
       expression.resolveMethod().getContainingClass().getName();
       expression.resolveMethod().getContainingClass().getQualifiedName();
}
```

Comment: By "from the javadocs to the APIs in question" - are you implying that the correct task would be to read... the entire API... to find the method? Because the getContainingClass is a member of a parent class, so it's not very obvious that one would first "resolve" then look up the hierarchy.